# Bounding $(x+y)^n$

Tags: algebra-precalculus

Let $n$ be a natural number. Is it possible to write $$(x+y)^n \leq C(x^n + y^n)$$ for some constant $C$??

It is obvious for $n=2$ (using Young's inequality) but not obvious to me for other $n$.

Let $x$ and $y$ be positive reals.

Comment: are x,y natural numbers?

Comment: No @teddybear, they can be any real positive number

Comment: Yes. $\frac{x^n +y^n}{2} \geq \left(\frac{x+y}{2}\right)^n. $

Comment: It would be interesting to calculate the _smallest_ constant $C$ such that $(x+y)^n\leq C(x^n+y^n)$ holds for all positive real numbers $x$ and $y$. PVAL's answer shows $C=2^{n}$ works but perhaps there is a smaller value that works.

Comment: Sorry, using (midpoint) convexity of $f(x)=x^n$ shows Raghav's inequality which is sharp because of $x=y=1$.

Comment: For a proof of Raghav's assertion ($C = 2^{n-1}$), see [my answer here](http://math.stackexchange.com/a/872415/1508).

Answer (score 13, accepted):

$$(x+y)^n\leq(2\operatorname{Max}(x,y))^n\leq2^n(x^n+y^n)$$

Comment: What is the proof for this please?

Comment: @SandeepSilwal : this is straightforward. Perhaps a line to explain the last inequality would help make people understand.

Comment: @SandeepSilwal: Either $\operatorname{Max}(x, y)^{n}\leq x^{n}$ or $\operatorname{Max}(x, y)^{n}\leq y^{n}$… So in any case, $\operatorname{Max}(x, y)^{n}\leq x^{n}+y^{n}$.