# Exponential inequality with $p \geq 1$

Tags: real-analysis, inequality

is it true that for all $p \geq 1, a,b  \geq  0:  (a+b)^{p} \leq 2^{p-1}(a^{p}+b^{p})$? If so, could someone give me a proof and an intuition of why this is true?

Thanks!

Comment: [This answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/872461) addresses your question, although the question there only asks about $(a+b)^p\le2^p\left(a^p+b^p\right)$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The inequality can be written as
$$
\left(\frac{a+b}2\right)^p\leqslant\frac 12a^p+\frac 12b^p
$$
which is (since $p\geqslant 1$), nothing but convexity of the map $t\in [0,\infty)\mapsto t^p$.

If we do not know about convexity, it is still possible to show the inequality by assuming without loss of generality that  $b=1$ and discuss the sign of the difference of the involved terms but looking at the derivative.

Comment: Indeed: https://math.stackexchange.com/a/143183/42969